# Backbone.js multiple delegateEvents for view

Tags: backbone.js

Quick question regarding delegateEvents in a View - can we specify multiple event bindings in a single event definition?

For example, instead of:

```
'keyup .text-input': 'textEvents',
'keydown .text-input': 'textEvents',
'focusin .text-input': 'textEvents',
'focusout .text-input': 'textEvents',
'click .text-input': 'textEvents',
...
```

Is this possible?

```
'keyup keydown focusin focusout click .text-input': 'textEvents',
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do that. From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents):

> Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`

The `event` is implicitly a single word (just like in jQuery and the DOM events) whereas `selector` can be any jQuery-style selector. Furthermore, the keys in `this.events` are parsed using [this regex](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1152):

```
var delegateEventSplitter = /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/;
```

so the `event` is the first component and only the first component.

You could build the `events` object yourself and call `delegateEvents` by hand with something like this:

```
var catch  = ['keyup', 'keydown', 'focusin', 'focusout', 'click'];
var events = { };
_(catch).each(function(ev) { events[ev + ' .text-input'] = 'textEvents' });
this.delegateEvents(events);
```

Comment: I put together a JSFiddle that demonstrates how this doesn't work" http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/hFAAC/ which is too bad, cause jQuery supports it. It's just Backbone doesn't. Maybe I'll submit a pull request to Backbone for this. :)

Comment: @Derick: But it might get ugly. Backbone splits the key into two pieces so that it can `this.$el.delegate(selector, eventName, method);` so you'd have to know how to extract the pieces but that would be rather difficult in the face of custom events; you'd have to try to figure out where the CSS selector starts instead of recognizing a list of events.

Comment: good point. there would have to be some other marker to distinguish the selector from the events

Comment: Was purely interested if anyone had come across this before and had a solution! This came about from porting existing jQuqery event handlers to Backbone. The first method works just fine, was just trying to clean up some code! :)

Comment: @crawf: jQuery can handle multiple events in one string. The problem is that Backbone combines the events and the selector in one string and there is no reliable way to separate two space delimited lists when faced with both custom events and selectors.